# Google Reader API request token, get 400:Bad Request

Tags: android, apache, http, google-reader, google-account

this Android code worked fine before, but i'm having problems for some reason.  here is the request i'm trying to make:

https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token

i'm getting 400:Bad Request as a response, and i'm not sure why. isn't this the correct URL for requesting a token?  the auth token is being passed as a header in all requests now, and i can request feed list, and it works just fine, so there's nothing wrong with the auth code.  what gives?

in addition, i can request a token in a normal browser, like Chrome, and get a token as a response body.  so the request itself is not the problem.  i just can't figure out what is wrong with my requests in code...

Comment: Show the code sending the request. Are you sure it is making a GET request.

Comment: i'm certain it's a GET.  the code is a bit lengthy... i've tried using GET and POST, to no avail.  i've tried sending it with and without the auth header (using ClientLogin).  and i've tried it with and without the old SID value in the cookie store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is to use http rather than https.  if anyone else is having trouble getting tokens from the unofficial google reader api, check whether you are using secure http or not.